Difficulty making HTTP request to VROOM and obtaining the list of optimized coordinates
The goal of my study is to optimize garbage collection routes. To achieve this, I utilized OpenStreetMaps to obtain a list of coordinates and, using OSRM, calculated the distance of the current route. With the same list of coordinates, I created a JSON file and used it with VROOM to obtain the distance of the optimized route. However, now I need to make an HTTP request to VROOM to obtain the list of coordinates of the optimized route.
That's my code:
# Generate VROOM file:
def generateVROOMFile(data):

  # Lists for vehicles and jobs
  vehicles = []  # (Initially, I will only implement one vehicle, for now, this list is useless)
  jobs = []

  start_coord = [data.longitude[0], data.latitude[0]]  # Garage position
  end_coord = [data.longitude.iloc[-1], data.latitude.iloc[-1]]  # Landfill position

  # Add a single vehicle
  vehicle = {
      "id": 1,
      "start": start_coord,
      "end": end_coord,
      "steps": [
          {"type": "start"}
      ]
  }

  # Adding steps
  for j in range(len(data.latitude) - 1):
    vehicle["steps"].append({"type": "job", "id": j+1})
  vehicle["steps"].append({"type": "end"})

  # Add the vehicle to the list of vehicles
  vehicles.append(vehicle)

  # Adding "jobs" for each coordinate
  for i in range(len(data.latitude) - 1):

    coord = [data.longitude[i], data.latitude[i]]

    job = {
        "id": i+1,
        "description": data.logradouro[i],
        "location": coord
    }
    jobs.append(job)

  # Create the VROOM object
  vroom_data = {
      "vehicles": vehicles,
      "jobs": jobs
  }

  # # Save the data to a file
  with open(f'VROOM_{data.name}.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(vroom_data, f, indent=2)

  return vroom_data


# Get optimized coordinates from VROOM
def getOptimizedCoords(vroom_data):

  # Local address of the VROOM server
  vroom_url = 'http://localhost:3000'

  # Send a POST request to the local VROOM API
  response = requests.post(vroom_url, json=vroom_data)

  # Check if the request was successful (status 200)
  if response.status_code == 200:
    return response.json()
  else:
    print("Error querying VROOM API:", response.status_code)
    return None

The message error is: 500. I'm in doubt because in the documentation the port would be 3000, but when I run VROOM in the terminal with "npm run serve" it opens on port 9966. However, when I update the port to 9966, the error code becomes: 404.

what is the status code you're receiving, is there any other text you receive with the response?

The error message is:
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc2ab313c70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

is the thing that's supposed to run on localhost:5000 actually running, do you get any errors over there? also please update the question with this information
